# Docker image .Net Framework Application

Tags: docker

I need to deploy my azure function app project in a Docker.
Is there any possible way to create a .netframework Application and deploy in docker? Adding a docker image for a Project. If is possible, can you help with image content?

My Application Framework version is 4.7.2.Is this possible

Comment: You can base your image on one of the .NET framework images found here: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet-framework/. But you will have to run the container on a Windows Docker host. You can't run it on a Linux Docker host.

Comment: This is working linux Only.I will working in the Windows based this images are not supported...